# SQL script - find most recent amount, and total

Tags: sql

Have a SQL table that i'm struggling with.  Have tried several methods.

Basically I have a list of orders by customer name.  Millions of records (it's a full export of a database; I know there are better methods, but this was the only format I was able to get the data in)

Format is as follows:

```
CustomerName  Date                    Amount
ABC           2018-01-08 11:05 PM     $0.15
ABC           2018-01-15 12:45 PM     $5.11
DEF           2017-03-03 5:28 PM      $15.89
GHI           2015-05-09 9:42 AM      $0.82
ABC           2018-09-16 9:30 AM      $9.15
JKL           2018-03-09 10:14 PM     $5.26
MNO           2018-06-12 2:09 AM      $0.92
JKL           2018-11-30 3:05 AM      $62.77
DEF           2017-03-11 4:19 PM      $10.62
```

Basically I'm trying to get a list of each unique customer (by NAME), and then the date of the FIRST order, the date of the LAST order, and the total amount they've spent with us

Example:

```
Customer     First Order      Last Order      Total
ABC          2018-01-08       2018-09-16      $14.41
DEF          2017-03-03       2017-03-11      $26.51
```

etc

So I've been able to do this by exporting the data to Excel, manually, then using vlookups, but it's hard as there are millions of rows of data, so I have to look up each 'column' separately basically (first order, last order, sum, etc)

EDIT:  I realized why this was so hard.  I'm new to SQL, but apparently the date is not the right field type.  So I was able to see the date, but not able to sort or sum it.
I ended up having to export the table and then re-import it selecting the correct field type for date.

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP BY`.

Comment: your ABC first value for total is wrong

Comment: What flavor of SQL? And Version?

Comment: `SELECT Customer, min(date),max(date), sum(amount) FROM table GROUP BY Customer`. It is such a simple and basic query that I do not even give it as an answer

Comment: Thank you - looks like it's way more basic than I expected :(

Comment: @nikhilsugandh - the total is correct.  double check what I wrote - there are three values - one is a little further down in the list :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use aggregate function like below

```
select customer, min(date) as fisrt_order,max(date) last_order,
sum(amount) as Total from table_name
group by customer
```

Comment: Thank you; i'm new to 'Group by' - I need to brush up on that.  My SQL skills are apparently really basic

Answer (score 2):

It's quite straight forward.

```
SELECT MIN(date) as First Date, MAX(date) as Last Order, SUM(amount) as Total
From table 
GROUP BY Customer
```

Comment: Thank you - I just added 'Customer' as the first select before MIN(date), and that did it.